# Any way to send alert when a node in Kubernetes scales up/down

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a kubernetes cluster in Amazon EKS, Autoscaling is set. So when there is load increase a new node spin-up in the cluster and spin-down with respect to load-running. We are monitoring it with Prometheus and send desired alerts with Alertmanager.

So help me with a query that will send alerts whenever Autoscaling is performed in my Cluster.

Comment: how have you configured autoscaling? if it done via Prometheus metric then you can use the same for alerts as well probably.

Comment: Thanks for your response, have configured autoscaling in EKS and monitoring our kubernetes cluster via Prometheus. Prometheus query will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not so great, but this works for me in a non-EKS Self Hosted Kubernetes Cluster on AWS EC2s.

```
(group by (kubernetes_io_hostname, kubernetes_io_role) (container_memory_working_set_bytes ) * 0
```

The above query fetches the currently up nodes and multiplies them by 0,

```
or group by (kubernetes_io_hostname, kubernetes_io_role) (delta ( container_memory_working_set_bytes[1m]))) == 1
```

Here, it adds all nodes that existed in the last 1 minute through the `delta()` function. The default value of the nodes in the `delta()` function output will be 1, but the existing nodes will be overridden by the value 0, because of the `OR` precedence. So finally, only the newly provisioned node(s) will have the value 1, and they will get filtered by the equality condition. You can also extract whether the new node is master/worker by the `kubernetes_io_role` label

Full Query:

```
(group by (kubernetes_io_hostname, kubernetes_io_role) (container_memory_working_set_bytes ) * 0 or group by (kubernetes_io_hostname, kubernetes_io_role) (delta ( container_memory_working_set_bytes[1m]))) == 1
```

You can reverse this query for downscaling of nodes, although that will collide with the cases in which your Kubernetes node Shuts Down Abruptly due to reasons other than AutoScaling